# Webserver compromised, strange processes running

Tags: top

So currently my debian server is generating large amount of outgoing traffic. Most likely compromised and used to attack other targets.

The top command shows this

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
15913 www-data  20   0 23268  920  696 R   7.0  0.1 525:25.24 -
10960 www-data  20   0 23268 2272  748 R   6.7  0.2   6137:34 -
10963 www-data  20   0 23268 2224  736 R   6.7  0.2 116:30.51 -
10972 www-data  20   0 23268 2368  736 R   6.7  0.2 116:16.23 -
10975 www-data  20   0 23268 2312  736 R   6.7  0.2 116:16.52 -
13509 www-data  20   0 10416  188  168 R   6.7  0.0   1242:09 64
15916 www-data  20   0 23268 2344  744 R   6.7  0.2 116:21.48 -
15925 www-data  20   0 23268 2336  744 R   6.7  0.2 116:21.37 -
15928 www-data  20   0 23268 2264  744 R   6.7  0.2 116:21.44 -
17906 www-data  20   0 23268 2276  748 R   6.7  0.2 115:09.06 -
18191 www-data  20   0 10416  224  204 R   6.7  0.0 275:54.55 64
17893 www-data  20   0 23268 2288  748 R   6.3  0.2 115:09.14 -
19789 www-data  20   0 23268 1124  708 R   6.3  0.1  19:33.81 -
26644 www-data  20   0  258m  17m 7108 S   4.7  1.7   0:09.78 apache2
26754 www-data  20   0  256m  11m 4900 R   3.0  1.1   0:00.72 apache2
 2832 mysql     20   0  748m  75m 3012 S   1.7  7.5 194:48.84 mysqld
17890 www-data  20   0 29440 2456  852 S   0.7  0.2   8:26.73 -
17903 www-data  20   0 29440 2452  852 S   0.7  0.2   8:27.18 -
19786 www-data  20   0 29440 2452  852 S   0.7  0.2   6:03.52 -
19773 www-data  20   0 29440 2452  852 S   0.3  0.2   6:03.28 -
19776 www-data  20   0 23268 2304  708 S   0.3  0.2   1:05.50 -
20044 www-data  20   0 23268 2364  708 S   0.3  0.2   1:02.34 -
26760 www-data  20   0 23268 2332  712 S   0.3  0.2   1520:05 -
26765 tyron     20   0 79820 1608  780 S   0.3  0.2   0:00.05 sshd
27145 www-data  20   0 23268 2368  696 S   0.3  0.2   4:00.71 -
    1 root      20   0 10656  124  100 S   0.0  0.0   0:04.71 init
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd
```

What are these processes that have '-' as command? How can I track down the source?
Apparently the attack comes through the http server since www-data is the user, but how? why? where? o.O

Comment: what does the apache logs say ?

Comment: you can get more information from the running processes from `/proc/[PID]/status`, there you could see the parent process, for example, and try to get some more information from where is it coming from (my motto: procfs is your friend)

Comment: Thank you, /procc/[pid] tells me these are perl processes run from /tmp

Comment: To build on @dave_alcarin 's comment, you can find out a lot of what the process is in `/proc/[PID]`, such as what the running binary actually is.  See http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start finding the executable using below command

```
ls -l /proc/<PID>/exe
```

Then you can find who created it (the parent PID) with running below command

```
ps -p <PID> -o ppid=:wq
```

And search until you find the starting point.

You can also check the common automatic execution points, like init scripts, global and user specific cron jobs, at scripts, rc.local files..
adding 1 more thing pls check google there are lots of post on same

Comment: As already commented by Andrew Henle looking into /proc helped, thank you